# AJAX Client side timeout instant notification

Tags: java, ajax, apache, jquery, timeout

I make a AJAX call request from a HTML page. I set & start a timer in the HTML page to show how much time it takes to receive a response back from server.

For one testing I see that in case Apache times out for a request (as server is taking long time to response) the AJAX call does not terminates. However I believe that my browser shows AJAX error when the backend script is trying to post as response after Apache timeout.

Is there a generic way that once Apache times out the AJAX call can immediately be notified of such an event - so that it can abort the request and show meaningful message to user in browser?

EDIT :: What does Apache KeepAlive ON parameter mean? Does it then mean that the connection in between Server and Browser would be in established mode and once Apache terminates the connection - browser would be notified?

EDIT:

Below is my AJAX call:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "/cgi-bin/my.py",
            success: function(xml)
            {
                alert('Success');
            },
            error:function(xhr,err,html)
            {
                    alert("Failed\nreadyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status + "\nresponseText: "+xhr.responseText);
            }
   });
```

Comment: If Apache times out this would (normally) send an error code header, which you can pick up in your callback and act accordingly. If you're using jQuery, any callback bound via `fail()` will fire in this eventuality.

Comment: Can you please provide some references of jQuery.fail(). I happen to find none for scenario mentioned in my post.

Comment: The point is your server response is (probably - check with whoever runs it) sending an error header. IF this is the case, you can receive and act on this with an error callback. I've just seen your edit, and you already have an error callback - `error:`.